# How to specify the start up condition in an oscillator simulation using Cadence Virtuoso?

Tags: oscillator, cadence

A real oscillator starts oscillating when there is some noise injected into its input. However, in Cadence virtuoso, how can I inject some noise into the input of the oscillator and make it oscillate?

Comment: What type of oscillator are you simulating? If it had a capacitor, give it some initial charge condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a three-stage ring oscillator. It has output capacitance at the output node.

Comment: Set the initial conditions so that one cap is high and the other two low -- that should be enough to get things started.  Expect it to take some cycles to settle out to steady state.

Comment: You do not need any noise....use an initial condition for one of the caps or use a power supply that is switched on at t=0 (that is the classical oscillation start in real life!)

Comment: Thanks all. I understand it now